# Should I use __stdcall on DLL export functions?

Tags: c, windows, dll, mingw-w64

I'm writing a small DLL in C using mingw-w64, which should be callable by VB.net programs.  The only exports are functions whose parameters and return types are primitive types.

Should I use `__stdcall` on the `dllexport` functions or not?

When searching the web I have seen examples both with and without it. There is discussion of how it affects name decoration but no advice as to whether this is a good thing or not, and what the impact is on my DLL's usability.

Comment: here question in next - are you can use different calling conventions from *VB.net* ? can you for example call (declare) exported function as `__fastcall` or `__cdecl` ? if can - you can use any calling conventions. if say *VB.net* can call only `__stdcall` external api - you need of course declare (explicit or implicit) export api as `__stdcall`

Comment: @RbMm I don't know what VB.net expects

Comment: i look - in *vb.net* you can use any by using [DllImportAttribute.CallingConvention](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.callingconvention?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) look also for [example](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3cbe88db-485b-42a6-b0e2-f56e79aa78fe/how-to-change-the-calling-convention-for-a-vbnet-project-in-vs-2017?forum=vbgeneral). so you can use any, which you want. simply `StdCall` is default. but you can use `Cdecl`, `FastCall` and even `ThisCall` if you export member function

Comment: @RbMm Does that mean that the VB developer will have to manually configure this setting in order to use my DLL , if I don't use stdcall ?

Comment: yes, need explicit declare `[DllImport("my.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention::Cdecl)]` my_func() for example for *__cdecl*. if you not use `CallingConvention` - will be `CallingConvention=CallingConvention::StdCall` by default

Answer (score 1):

There is really no good reason to use nondefault calling convention/ABI (`__stdcall` or otherwise) anywhere except when you need to call an existing interface defined that way. It's just gratuitous ugliness. Where it's done all over existing Windows stuff, it's legacy cargo culting from the Win16 era, and has no actual rationale behind it.

Comment: So you're saying I should not use it?

Comment: Right. I've clarified.